# how to create a windowed plug-in?

Tags: npapi, browser-plugin, windowless, windowed

I have created a safari plugin using NPAPI and I want to add a NSView in my plug-in.

When I try to get NPWindow throw function **NPP_SetWindow(NPP instance, NPWindow* window)**, the second parameter is nil.

I think my plug-in is windowless, but i don't know how to create a windowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPAPI on Mac does not support NSView as a windowing mode. There are two supported modes:

- [CoreAnimation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Plugins%3aCoreAnimationDrawingModel) (or [InvalidatingCoreAnimation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI%3aInvalidatingCoreAnimation) on Chrome and Firefox)
- [CoreGraphics](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI%3aCoreGraphicsDrawing)

There used to be a QuickDraw mode, but that's deprecated.

For more information, see [Stuart Morgan's excellent blog post on the subject](http://www.escapedthoughts.com/weblog/geek/P110308-mac-npapi-plugins.writeback).

It is possible to make a NSView render to a CoreGraphics context but you'd have to proxy all of the events and it is far from perfect.

**EDIT:** To further explain the answer to your question, the reason that the window parameter is NULL (it's a C api, not Obj C, so it's NULL, not nil... despite them being the same thing =]) is because in the [Cocoa Event Model](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI%3aCocoaEventModel) you get a CGContextRef as part of the [draw event](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI%3aCocoaEventModel#Draw_event) which is only valid during the context of that event.

Comment: Hello @taxilian! I want to konw why the second parameter "window" is nil? I find below code from apple developer document,but now it can't work.Did i miss something ?
NPError setwindow_cb(NPP instance, NPWindow* npw) {
    ...
 
    NP_CGContext *npcontext = npw.window;
    CGContextRef context = npcontext.context;
    CGRect boundingBox = CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context);

Comment: You missed the update to cocoa where the window is now NULL and you get the CGContextRef as part of the event. See https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI:CocoaEventModel

Comment: Thank you very much, taxilian.**NPWindow** is very important for me,because my player is created by export function `void SetHwnd(void *hWnd, CGRect rect)` in my plug-in.if CGContextRef is only can used,I should rewrite a new function?

Comment: If your current code requires that the CGContextRef come from the NPWindow instead of as part of the Cocoa NPEvent then yes, you will have to rewrite some code.